# System.ArgumentException - Filter string not valid

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, filter

I made a simple notepad in C# by following tutorial on YouTube. For the guy who made tutorial everything works fine but for me when I try to save a text file I wrote in `richTextBox1` it throws an error.

Error is: System.ArgumentException: 'Filter string you provided is not valid. The filter string must contain a description of the filter, followed by the vertical bar (|) and the filter pattern. The strings for different filtering options must also be separated by the vertical bar.
 Example: "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"'

```
{
    SaveFileDialog sv = new SaveFileDialog();
    sv.Filter="Text Document(*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)";
    if (sv.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       richTextBox1.SaveFile(sv.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
       this.Text = sv.FileName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be

```
sv.Filter="Text Document(*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
```